# Display DISTINCT value on SQL statement by column condition

Tags: sql, mariadb, conditional-statements, distinct

i'm introducing you the problem with DISTINCT values by column condition i have dealt with and can't provide
any idea how i can solve it.

So. The problem is i have two Stephen here declared , but i don't want duplicates:
**
The problem:
**

```
id  vehicle_id  worker_id    user_type   user_fullname
9   1              NULL         external_users     John Dalton   
10  1               16          employees          Mike            
11  1                1          employees          Stephen         
12  2               173         employee           Nicholas        
13  2                1          employee           Stephen         
14  1              NULL         external_users     Peter      
**
```

The desired output:**

```
id  vehicle_id  worker_id    user_type   user_fullname
9   1              NULL         external_users     John Dalton   
10  1               16          employees          Mike                 
12  2               173         employee           Nicholas        
13  2                1          employee           Stephen         
14  1              NULL         external_users     Peter
```

I have tried CASE statements but without success. When i group by it by worker_id,
it removes another duplicates, so i figured out it needs to be grouped by some special condition?
If anyone can provide me some hint how i can solve this problem , i will be very grateful.

Thank's!

Comment: You are writing you don't want duplicates, but your result does not contain any duplicate. The two Stephens have different vehicle id's, so they are no duplicates. Why do you want one of them only and how to decide which one? What should happen if a third Stephen with another vehicle id appears?

Comment: It contains duplicate , Stephen has two same worker_ids (  Stephen = worker_id = 1) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no duplicate rows in this table.  Just because Stephen appears twice doesn't make them duplicates because the ID, VEHICLE_ID, and USER_TYPE are different.

What you need to do is decide how you want to identify the Stephen record you wish to see in the output.  Is it the one with the highest VEHICLE_ID?  The "latest" record, i.e. the one with the highest ID?

You will use that rule in a window function to order the rows within your criteria, and then use that row number to filter down to the results you want.  Something like this:

```
select id, vehicle_id, worker_id, user_type, user_fullname
from (
    select id, vehicle_id, worker_id, user_type, user_fullname,
        row_number() over (partition by worker_id, user_fullname order by id desc) n
    from user_vehicle
) t
where t.n = 1
```

Comment: To be fair: An id is nearly never duplicated. So the fact the id differs does not tell us the entries are no duplicates. But as said, other columns differ, too.

Comment: @JonasMetzler true enough

Comment: Thank you sir , great answer. The solution was highest vehicle_id , because one worker cannot be defined twice for same vehicle.